# Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: laravel

Tried to execute

```
php artisan optimize
```

and got the following response

```
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
Route cache cleared!

   LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at /home/iconprep/app.iconpreparation.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919| 
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Routing\Route::prepareForSerialization()
      /home/iconprep/app.iconpreparation.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteCacheCommand.php:62

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::handle()
      /home/iconprep/app.iconpreparation.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:36

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

How I'll be able to prepare route & ease this error code? I migrated this code from git. And I am beginner to laravel.

Can anyone let me know the correct solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try after this command `php artisan optimize:clear`.

Comment: Could you edit your question by adding `'/'` url route. I want to ensure the route how you define?

Comment: Rework closure in rooute file to controller action